Add field to profile screen frozen in 5.76.alpha1
I have an instance of CiviCRM at 5.76.alpha1 under IIS. I cannot add fields to profiles, as the Add Field screen remains frozen. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this or point me in the right direction? There isn't a problem with the demo version.

Can you open the add field form in a new tab and submit the form? You should see error on the screen. In pop-up this fatal errors are not shown on screen unless you dig in browser console to check the response of the submission.

Yes, I can open it in a new tab, and then I can add the field - there is no error apparent.

Any notice erros?

Yes, there are some warnings and this:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()
at l._storageChangeDispatcher (content.js:2:855976)
at _storageChangeDispatcherCallback (content.js:2:855424)

That error disappeared when I disabled the Microsoft Editor extension, but the problem remained. I found this error:
Select element must have an accessible name: Element has no title attribute
In, I think:
